# C++ linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces

Source of `MaxSumOfSubArray.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace MaxSumOfSubArray {

    void run() {
        std::cout << "hey hey";
    }

}
```

Source of `main.cpp`:

```
#include "MaxSumOfSubArray.cpp"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    MaxSumOfSubArray::run();
    return 0;
}
```

But I get the error:

```
duplicate symbol __ZN16MaxSumOfSubArray3runEv in:
/Users/li.tonghui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CppChallenges-eobfuxlkqjfgebendxkoqbsvsbmr/Build/Intermediates/CppChallenges.build/Debug/CppChallenges.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o
/Users/li.tonghui/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CppChallenges-eobfuxlkqjfgebendxkoqbsvsbmr/Build/Intermediates/CppChallenges.build/Debug/CppChallenges.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/MaxSumOfSubArray.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: See my answer to a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579340/header-guards-do-not-seem-to-work/18580233#18580233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you include MaxSumOfSubArray.cpp in main.cpp AND try to compile it. Do one or the other, not both...

Hint: normally you wouldn't include a .cpp in another.cpp (you include .h files)

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to compile and in your command line

```
clang .... main.cpp  MaxSumOfSubArray.cpp
```

which is wrong since you already includes `MaxSumOfSubArray.cpp` in main.cpp, you dont need to specify it again.